# Do not add field with same data in firestore with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi I have started to add tokens of devices in firestore, I set tokens to firestore when ever the application is launched, I need a little help that my app should check first, if the token is same, then it must not add it in cloud fire store.
I am doing it in initstate, code is here:

```
firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){

DocumentReference documentReference = Firestore.instance.collection("DeviceToken").document();
  Map<String, dynamic> devToken ={
    "Token": token
  };
  documentReference.setData(devToken,merge: true).whenComplete((){
  print("$token created");
  });
  setState(() {});
  });
```

Comment: Save last token that you sent to persistent storage using [this plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) and then check, if it changes

Comment: @DimaRostopira by the way i think if i query the document and apply some logic there, so that it insert token other wise not, will it be helpful besides Shared preferences plugin?

Comment: Yeah, you can use transaction. But this will create unnecessary request to database, and you will pay for that. Just don't

Comment: @DimaRostopira then kindly guide a little how can i achieve the goal, i am stuck with this for two weeks.